# FTP Delete All Folders in Target Directory

Tags: php

What i am trying to do is to delete all files in my target servers folder, the folder all the files are in is: "**/public_html/**" this directory contains all the target files, i don't want to delete this folder as it must remain the intact, just everything inside.

```
function ftpDelete($conn, $directory) {   
        echo "<pre><b>FTP Files on Server:</b>\n";
        $filelist = ftp_nlist($conn, $directory);
        foreach($filelist as $file) { 
            // Do not show "." or ".."      
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                ftp_delete($conn, $directory);
                echo $file . "\n";  
            }                   
        }
        echo "</pre>";
}

// Run delete functions ...
ftpDelete($conn, "/public_html/");

// Files out that is still on the server ...
FTP Folders on Server:
/public_html/vendor
/public_html/stats
/public_html/icon
/public_html/images
```

This code so far will delete all files that is the "public_html" directory, but not any folders, i know from reading the folders need to be empty first, i'm not sure the best way to handle these folders, i didn't see a command that would delete the target folders and it's contents, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the filename after the directory:

```
ftp_delete($conn, "$directory/$file");
```